# Add an option in Exporting Menu of amCharts 4 to average data

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to find a way to quickly average data either weekly or monthly using the Exporting Menu in amCharts 4. I made this [codePen](https://codepen.io/laurent777/pen/OJdjwQa) but it doesn't work.

Can someone have a look to see what I am doing wrong?

The Exporting menu part looks like this:

```
chart.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu();
chart.exporting.menu.align = "right";
chart.exporting.menu.verticalAlign = "top";
chart.exporting.menu.items = [{
        "label": "<i class='fa fa-bars' ></i>",
        "menu": [
            { 
                "label": "Average",
                "menu": [
                    { "type": "custom", "label": "All", "options":
                        { "callback":
                            function() {
                                dateAxis.groupData = false;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    { "type": "custom", "label": "Week", "options":
                        { "callback":
                            function() {
                                dateAxis.groupData = true;
                                lineSeries.groupFields.valueY = "average";
                                lineSeries.groupInterval = { timeUnit: "week", count: 1 };
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    { "type": "custom", "label": "Month", "options":
                        { "callback":
                            function() {
                                dateAxis.groupData = true;
                                lineSeries.groupFields.valueY = "average";
                                lineSeries.groupInterval = { timeUnit: "month", count: 1 };
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
}];
```

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If it can help someone, I had the answer from @zeroin in another forum:

The functions should be like this...

```
lineSeries.groupFields.valueY = "average";  
dateAxis.groupInterval = { timeUnit: "week", count: 1 };
dateAxis.groupData = true;
```

Cheers